# Partial (regional?) DNS failure: some S3 amazonaws.com servers are not resolving

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services

A friend of mine has been using AWS S3 with CyberDuck and S3 Browser for a long time, and all was working fine for him yesterday. This evening, both CyberDuck and S3 Browser are reporting DNS errors.

He is in southern California and I'm in Seattle. We compared some `ping` tests. For me, all of the following S3 AWS server names resolve fine:

```
ping s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
ping s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
ping s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
ping s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

My friend was only able to `ping s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` -- but later that stopped working as well.

I helped him reconfigure his Ethernet DNS settings to make `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS) the primary DNS server. He also rebooted his computer and his cable modem. Nonetheless the DNS problems persist, and CyberDuck and S3 Browser are still unable to access S3.

For me:

```
> nslookup s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address:  52.217.85.182
```

For him:

```
>nslookup s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

* dns.google can't find s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Server failed
```

He then drove to a friend's house who has a different ISP, but he still couldn't access S3. And all this was working yesterday.

I've never seen such a partial (and apparently regional?) DNS failure. What could be going wrong here? Any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Usually you just wait until it shakes itself out upstream.

Comment: And how long might that take? We were checking over the course of 1-2 hours.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? If you've eliminated several DNS sources, ISP, Google,  OpenDNS, CloudFlare etc & have the same issue with them all, and double-checked by pinging a resolved address, I don't see there's much to do but wait, or ask your ISP. DNS as a global entity is programmed to find new routes if existing routes are unavailable - sometimes it just takes a bit longer than others.

Comment: BTW, I can't get a result for that either, London, UK, using 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 - but I can with my ISP's regular DNS [Virgin].

Comment: Works for me too. You should really ask for help from AWS Support. BTW, `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` redirects to `https://aws.amazon.com`.

Comment: As of this morning, it's working again. I wonder how it's possible that I was able to resolve the name through `8.8.8.8`, but my friend (and @Tetsujin) was not.

Comment: I still can't get it over 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 - I guess it's taking some time to shake out. You ought to have failback in your DNS assignment - see https://www.cloudns.net/blog/what-is-a-dns-outage-dns-downtime-and-how-to-avoid-it/ for a general guide.